# Algorithm for detecting pairs occurring in a long list

Tags: performance, algorithm, list, search, count

Given a long sequence of N (not necessary distinct) numbers, say

```
{1, 50, 3, 99, 1, 2, 100, 99, 4, 100, 4, 100} (could be very long)
```

and a small set of M ordered pairs, say

```
(1, 2)

(2, 1)

(1, 3)    

(99, 50)

(99, 100)
```

I would like to detect whether the ordered pair occurs **anywhere** in the list (they could be separated, but **order matters**).  For example, the counts above would be:

```
(1, 2): 2 (each 1 pairs with the later 2)

(2, 1): 0 (no 1's come after the 2)

(1, 3): 1 (only one of the 1's come before the 3)

(99, 50): 0 (no 99's come before the 50)

(99, 100): 5 (3 times for the first 99 and 2 times for the second)
```

Assuming that every number in the ordered pairs is guaranteed to appear in the list, does there exist an algorithm to extract these counts faster than the naive O(N * M) time (achieved by brute force searching for each ordered pair)?

As a side question, might there be a fast algorithm if we restrict ourselves to boolean occurrences only instead of counts?  That is:

```
(1, 2): yes

(2, 1): no

(1, 3): yes

(99, 50): no

(99, 100): yes
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Restricting yourself to Boolean occurrences could help a lot - consider the extreme case where all the pairs you are looking for come first in the population.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Keep two hashes, one mapping numbers to the least position at which they occur, and one mapping numbers to the greatest position at which they occur. The ordered pair (a, b) appears in order if least[a] < greatest[b] (and both hash keys are present). Preprocessing time is linear, space usage is linear, query time is constant (under standard assumptions about the complexity of hashing).

As for the counting version, the best I can think of is to keep one hash mapping each number to the positions at which it occurs in sorted order. To query a pair, "merge" the position lists, keeping track of the number of a-elements so far and the number of pair occurrences. When a b-element is selected to be next, increment the number of pairs by the number of a-elements. When an a-element is selected to be next, increment the number of a-elements. (If a == b, return length choose 2.)

Comment: So to clarify, the mapping step takes O(N) and doesn't touch the pairs, and after that's done we look for each pair for a total O(N + M) time overall?  And for counting, your algorithm is still O(N * M) right, since the merge step can take O(N) time?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an O(n) solution...

```
unordered_map<int, unordered_set<int>> pairs = ...;

void process(int n)
{
    // keep list of pairs that have their first seen, indexed by second...
    static unordered_map<int, vector<pair<int,int>>> live;

    // if next item is in live list, we have found some pairs...
    for (auto found_pair : live[n])
        process(found_pair);

    // add pairs to live list that have a first of the current item
    for (auto pair : pairs[n])
        for (auto second : pair.second)
           live.insert(second, make_pair(pair.first, second));
}
```

Comment: I'd say one table mapping from first-of-pair to second-of-pair, then build another table keyed on seconds-of-pairs you are looking for.

Comment: I thought that he was interested in consecutive pairs.  Rereading question it looks more complicated.

Answer (score 1):

You can keep a list of active pairs, and loop through the list of numbers. Whenever you find the first number of a pair, you copy the pair to the active list. Whenever you find the second number of a pair in the active list, you increase the count for that pair.

Example in C#:

```
public class Pair {

  public int First { get; private set; }
  public int Second { get; private set; }
  public int Count { get; set; }

  public Pair(int first, int second) {
    First = first;
    Second = second;
    Count = 0;
  }

}

int[] values = {1, 50, 3, 99, 1, 2, 100, 99, 4, 100, 4, 100};

List<Pair> pairs = new List<Pair>();
pairs.Add(new Pair(1, 2));
pairs.Add(new Pair(2, 1));
pairs.Add(new Pair(1, 3));
pairs.Add(new Pair(99, 50));
pairs.Add(new Pair(99, 100));

List<Pair> active = new List<Pair>();

foreach (int value in values) {
  foreach (Pair p in active) {
    if (p.Second == value) {
      p.Count++;
    }
  }
  foreach (Pair p in pairs) {
    if (p.First == value) {
      active.Add(p);
    }
  }
}

foreach (Pair p in pairs) {
  Console.WriteLine("({0},{1}) : Count: {2}", p.First, p.Second, p.Count);
}
```

Output:

```
(1,2) : Count: 2
(2,1) : Count: 0
(1,3) : Count: 1
(99,50) : Count: 0
(99,100) : Count: 5
```

Improvement thoughts:

- You can use a `Dictionary<int, List<Pair>>` for the lists of pairs.
- You can put an active count in the pair, so instead of adding another reference in the active list, you increase the active count.

Answer (score -2):

Suppose all number are different don't you think that brute force solution is the only solution.

Comment: Do you have any basis to make that claim? Sort the list and maintain pointers to original indexes, and for each pair check the indexes. Costs `O((N+M)logN)`.

Comment: Oh, I thought if all the numbers are different there would be O(N*M) pairs, thus extracting these pair would take O(N*M) operations atleast. Ofcourse find the number of times a particular pair occurs is quite different.

Comment: @davin you should write your comment as an answer

Comment: @F.C., you can have it. Enjoy!

Comment: @davin Sorting the list will reorder elements, so we will not be able to distinguish pair (1,2) from (2,1). I don't think that sorting can help to solve the problem.